# Can't connect to yesod server

Tags: yesod

I followed [this](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/basics) tutorial, and I've tried it on Windows 8, a clean install of Windows 7, and Ubuntu (all on the same computer and router). It works on Ubuntu, but the browser fails to ever connect to localhost:3000 (or any port I specify in the code) with Windows 7 and Windows 8. However, connecting to ruby on rails at localhost:3000 does work on Windows 7 and Windows 8. So far, I've played around with the hosts file, running as administrator, using ghc, using yesod devel, firewalls, and more. Nothing has worked. I assume given these constraints that it's a bug in yesod, but maybe there's a hack around it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there was a bug for a few days with the version of Warp on Hackage which prevented it from working on Windows. Any more recent version of Warp should work correctly.